# py2applet: command not found

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to create a GUI Python app using Py2App, but am having trouble running the setup script py2applet.

I've installed py2app via pip

```
$ sudo pip install py2app #this works ok
```

Then, I try to build the setup script:

```
$ py2applet --make-setup gui.py #this fails w/ no command found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try refreshing your shells' memory or try to call the app with full path just to see if that works.  E.g. /usr/bin/py2applet

You can use

```
sudo find / -name "py2applet" -type f
```

To find the location if you don't know.

Eg bash would have the hash -r  command to refresh itself. http://ss64.com/bash/hash.html

Answer (score 3):

Find the executable:

```
sudo find / -name "py2applet" -type f
```

Then add its parent directory to your PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:YOUR_PATH_HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the commands in:

Python 2.7

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/bin/py2applet
```

Python 3.7

```
/Users/development/Library/Python/3.7/bin/py2applet
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw in normal operation it should be in `/usr/local/bin/`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 admin  admin  296 21 Apr  2015 /usr/local/bin/py2applet
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mac OS X:

```
$ sudo pip install py2app
```

After installing py2app using pip:

```
$ python /Users/user/site-packages/py2app/script_py2applet.py --make-setup MyApplication.py
```

This works as well as using the py2applet command. If the py2app folder was installed elsewhere, be sure to include the full directory.