# Mac: Terminal stuck while building python app with and without py2app

Tags: python, macos, terminal, py2app

Okay, so, I was finishing my project and I wanted to convert all the files to .app. I typed `python main_gui.py py2app` into the terminal (I already made my way to the folder with the file using `cd` command). 
But, instead of building the app, nothing happed. When I tried to close terminal to try again, it warned me that I'll kill an existing process. Tried same thing with just `python main_gui.py build`, nothing changed. Is Terminal freaking out or I am freaking out?

Answer (score 0):

Py2app official documentation: https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#building-for-deployment

> Building a redistributable application consists of simply running the
>   py2app command:
>
> ```
> $ python setup.py py2app
> ```

So you need to have a `setup.py` file. For what I see, you are not passing that argument into such file. To generate a `setup.py`, the docs say:

> #### Create a setup.py file The first step is to create a setup.py file for your script. setup.py is the “project file” that tells setuptools
>
> everything it needs to know to build your application. We’ll use the
>   py2applet script to do that:
>
> ```
> $ py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
> ```

Comment: I found a similar instructions [here](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/), but when I typed `py2applet --make-setup main_gui.py` it said that command "py2applet" doesn't exist. I decided to make setup.py by myself, could it be the problem?

Comment: If the command does not exist it means you have misconfigured something.

Comment: @TheDeveloper please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064657/py2applet-command-not-found  You have to create the file with the indicated tools, unless you actually know very well what you are doing by creating it yourself. That is most likely the cause of your error

Comment: Also if the error still persists please indicate so in this comment section